# New posts and post changes don't have their MathJax parsed.

Tags: bug, mathjax

You know the small grey box that says "a new answer has been added" and when you click it the answer appears? Yeah well, MathJax is not parsed. Look:

[image]

I got that post when I clicked the grey box. I had to refresh the page to see the parsed text. Additionally, another grey box appeared saying that the answer was edited, I clicked it and it still was not parsed.

I am using Google Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit), running on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5.

**Edit**: It also happens with comments. Weird.

Comment: This seems to be similar to this bug report; [MathJax not rendering in comments and post preview](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/mathjax-not-rendering-in-comments-and-post-preview). (They are not the same, but at least the part about comments is an overlap. And I would not be surprised, if we later find out that they are caused by the same thing.)

Comment: Using the latest edition of chrome as of 9/28 I have been getting the same error for days now... It seems to also happen when I post a comment, but not when I post an answer. Very weird.

Comment: This seems similar to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21530/26910. Could you check and cross post to the 2.6-beta thread if it's not?